# Mismatch between PointerPressed and PointerReleased events

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, directx, monogame

I was using Monogame and had an issue whereby if I rapidly placed lots of fingers on the screen and then quickly removed them, eventually (after a few repeats) I would end up with some 'Pressed' events that never got a matching 'Released' event.

I don't think the issue is with Monogame though as I can reproduce the issue (on my Nokia Lumia 920) with a tiny 'Windows Phone and Direct3D' App created using vs2012.

On the C++ side I just store a vector inside the generated Direct3DInterop class that records pressed events and released events

```
void Direct3DInterop::OnPointerPressed(DrawingSurfaceManipulationHost^ sender, PointerEventArgs^ args)
{
    uint32 pointerID = args->CurrentPoint->PointerId;

    auto i = std::find (_pressed.begin(), _pressed.end(), pointerID);
    if (i == _pressed.end())
        _pressed.push_back(pointerID);
}
void Direct3DInterop::OnPointerReleased(DrawingSurfaceManipulationHost^ sender, PointerEventArgs^ args)
{
    uint32 pointerID = args->CurrentPoint->PointerId;

    _pressed.erase(std::remove(_pressed.begin(), _pressed.end(), pointerID),       _pressed.end());
}
```

In my XAML, I just have a textblock and a dispatch timer that periodically checks the count of elements in _pressed (it should always return to 0).

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" 
  Margin="0,115,0,0">
<DrawingSurface x:Name="DrawingSurface" Margin="0,-113,0,0" Loaded="DrawingSurface_Loaded"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="LostReleasedCount" Text="Lost released count = 0"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-113,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="113"  Width="480"/>

</Grid>
```

and in the code behind file

```
private Direct3DInterop m_d3dInterop = null;
private DispatcherTimer _timer;
private int _seconds;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    // Creates a new instance of a timer.
    _timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    // Tells the _timer to tick every  second.
    _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);


   _timer.Tick += TimerOnTick;
    _timer.Start();
    _seconds = 0;

}

private void TimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        _seconds++;
        LostReleasedCount.Text = "Lost released count = " + m_d3dInterop.GetPressedCount().ToString();
    });
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Should you always expect the pressed events and the released events to match? I cannot reproduce the problem if I use XAML directly with a Touch.FrameReported event so it's presumably some issue with DirectX?

Without a matching pressed/released pair, I'm not sure how to distinguish a genuine problem from someone just holding their finger on the screen and not moving it.

Comment: did you find out a solution for your problem? I got the same problem and it leads to button sticking issue in my app. My workaround is to add a "Reset" button so that the user can reset all touch response to zero.

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208971:

> Other events instead of PointerReleased may fire at the end of the action—for example, PointerCanceled or PointerCaptureLost. Don't rely on PointerPressed and PointerReleased events always occurring in pairs. To function properly, your app must listen for and handle all events that represent likely conclusions to the Press action. Some of the reasons why you might not get a PointerReleased occurrence are:

- Differences in how specific hardware handles touch actions and Press actions
- A programmatic pointer capture from a different pointer
- User actions that change the relationship of the display area, such as changing resolution or monitor settings
- Input interactions such as a stylus touching the same surface as a previous touch action

Comment: This may not be the case because `Direct3DInterop` is derived from `Windows::Phone::Input::Interop::IDrawingSurfaceManipulationHandler` and doesn't have these 2 additional events.

Answer (score 0):

There may be another reason. Please see my answer here: [How to handle multi touch in windows phone 8 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641199/how-to-handle-multi-touch-in-windows-phone-8-app/22354919#22354919)

Possible reason of this can be **race condition**.

Answer (score 0):

add this function in Direct3DBackground class

```
void Direct3DBackground::SetManipulationHost(Windows::Phone::Input::Interop::
             DrawingSurfaceManipulationHost^ manipulationHost)
{
    manipulationHost->PointerPressed +=
                      ref new TypedEventHandler<
              DrawingSurfaceManipulationHost^, PointerEventArgs^>
              (this, &Direct3DBackground::OnPointerPressed);

    manipulationHost->PointerMoved +=
        ref new TypedEventHandler<DrawingSurfaceManipulationHost^, 
         PointerEventArgs^>(this, &Direct3DBackground::OnPointerMoved);

    manipulationHost->PointerReleased +=
        ref new TypedEventHandler<DrawingSurfaceManipulationHost^, 
         PointerEventArgs^>(this, &Direct3DBackground::OnPointerReleased);
}
```

and in XAML C# code:

```
DrawingSurfaceBackground.SetBackgroundManipulationHandler(m_d3dBackGround);
```